# How does a sonic black hole (or dumb hole) work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, black-holes, acoustics, hawking-radiation, phonons

I came across this term and apparently they used [sonic black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_black_hole) to detect something analogous to Hawking Radiation, but I have failed to find sources which explain how exactly they work and how they are created!

Comment: Oren Lahav, et al. "Realization of a Sonic Black Hole Analog in a Bose-Einstein Condensate." Physical Review Letters 105, 240401 (2010).

Comment: $\uparrow$ aka [arXiv:0906.1337](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1337).

Comment: I don't think I understand quite a few parts of the paper but it indeed a useful reference and all.